# Starting Activity with back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an application in android, where i'm looking for a solution.

There is an Activity(say A1) from which by clicking a button, user goes to another Activity(say A2). Now once the user has finished with A2 activity, he clicks back-button, to go back to previous activity A1. 
Well this is a very known fact that, A1 will resume automatically at this point.

But I want it in a different way (because my application demands that).

Once if i go to activity A2 from A1, A1 is destroyed; and while being in A2 if back-button is clicked, A1 is created again.

Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: What's the special point that A1 must be destroyed and be re-created? If you have some processes that are done during onCreate() in your case, I think you could probably move most of your codes in onCreate() to onResume().

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778754/kill-activity-on-back-button which may help.

Thanks,
Developerjigar

Comment: @VictorWong~~ tried that already, didn't worked. but it seems like i need to re-create it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use:

```
public void onBackPressed()  
{  
    //do whatever you want the 'Back' button to do  
    //as an example the 'Back' button is set to start a new Activity named 'NewActivity'  
    this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,NewActivity.class));  

    return;  
}
```

look at here: http://www.41post.com/1685/programming/android-changing-the-back-button-behaviour

Comment: I am not sure if this meet his needs, as he wants to make A1 to be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the Back Button key press like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {

     switch(keyCode) {
     case(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK):
          Intent a1_intent = new Intent(this, A1Activity.class);
          startActivity(a1_intent);
          finish();
          return true;



     }
     return false;
}
```

[Take a look at this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {  
    finish();
    return;  
}
```